# ArcGIS REST API invalid URL JSON

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I'm using the ArcGIS REST API to create an OD cost matrix by using this link https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/OriginDestinationCostMatrix/GPServer/GenerateOriginDestinationCostMatrix/submitJob?.
However, when using a feature service URL to create the OD cost matrix, using Postman I always get the same error.

When I have origins and destinations equal to an array as specified here https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/network/api-reference/origin-destination-cost-matrix-service.htm, it all works well. However, when I use a feature service URL this happens.

```
origins = {"url":"http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/MapServer/1/query?where=Name=%27Indian%20Consulate,%20San%20Francisco%27&outFields=Name,RouteName&f=json"}

destinations = {"url":"http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/MapServer/1/query?where=Name=%27Ghirardelli%20Square%27&outFields=Name,RouteName&f=json"}
```

I always get this error

```
{
"type": "esriJobMessageTypeInformative",
"description": "Submitted."
},
{
"type": "esriJobMessageTypeInformative",
"description": "Executing..."
},
{
"type": "esriJobMessageTypeError",
"description": "Invalid value for parameter Origins - Details : invalid URL json "
},
{
"type": "esriJobMessageTypeError",
"description": "Failed."
}
]
}
```

Comment: SampleServer3 is a 10.0, sp5 Server. I'd suggest trying a new Server, something at least 10.1. The REST end point for query looks different from 10.0 to 10.1+ -- its possible the result object is different as well, thus why it's not working. (Simply taking your Origins URL... that is NOT passing back expected geometry, its more like a definition of the layer)

Comment: @KHibma can you give a more concrete example? I really didn't understand your answer. What is 10.0 or 10.1? How can I try a new server? How can I pass back the expected geometry? The link is using the examples they give, that's why I use that one.

Comment: Looking at the doc, and seeing where they used SampleServer3, their URL actually is returning features. Try using exactly what is there: `http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/MapServer/6/query?where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&f=json`

Comment: @KHibma ok, but the example you give shows paths not points. Therefor, it makes it impossible to calculate the distance between them. The OD cost matrix calculates the distance between an origin and a destination. But if I give a path already then it defeats the purpose of having an OD matrix. Actually that example is only for calculating polyline barriers. My example is still what they use though.

Comment: Then you'll need to find a service that provides the output you need and build a query that returns proper geometry in the JSON object. I'm simply showing you the problem in your origins as it's not returning something the service wants. Take the URL and paste it into a browser and see for yourself.

Comment: @KHibma thank you. So I've fixed the links and they both return the same as your link. Still the same error. Am I missing something then?